# Get selected ListView item after using Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, contextmenu, selecteditem

I'm coding a simple music player in WPF with ListView containing my mp3 files.
After MouseDoubleClick I get selected item this way:

```
private void PlayNow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem;
   if (item != null)
   {
       //Some code here
   }
}
```

But when I do the same via ContextMenu, my selected item is ContextMenu.Item.
I still need the ListView selected item tho.
How can I get it via ContextMenu?

Comment: From looking at the wpf documentation, `ContextMenu` has a `Parent` property.

Comment: @Delous ContextMenu's parent is popup, which has no parent.

Comment: What about getting the ListView's SelectedItem directly, not via sender object?

Comment: @Tigran managed to get it with method called on MouseRightButtonUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the item the `ContextMenu` belongs to using the [`PlacementTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget) property.

If you want to do this the "proper" way, though, I might suggest reading up on [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview). You could bind both the double-click action and the `ContextMenu`'s item to [`MediaCommands.Play`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mediacommands.play), and pass the corresponding item by binding it to `CommandParameter`.

Comment: Using PlacementTarget works just as expected, thanks!